# SQL query to join two tables, adding new records if records missing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, both with same data:

```
IP address | count
```

I need to combine the two tables into new one that contains data from both original tables.

- IF there is a matching record in both tables, their **count** should be added.
- IF there is a record that exists only in one table it gets copied over to the new table.

Let first table be called ip_data_january, second called ip_data_february and the one I am trying to create is ip_data_yearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use exists clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `IP_Data_Yearly` table is empty, an `INSERT` with a subquery that aggregates count by IP should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO IP_Data_Yearly
  SELECT IP_Address, SUM(Count)
  FROM (
    SELECT IP_Address, Count FROM IP_Data_January
    UNION ALL SELECT IP_Address, Count FROM IP_Data_February
  ) IPCombined
  GROUP BY IP_Address
```

Answer (score 2):

1st insert only new ip addresses   (with count starting at zero)

```
 insert into ip_data_yearly (ip_adress, count) 
    (select distinct ip_address, '0' from jan_table 
    where ip_addess not in (select ip_adress from  ip_data_yearly);
```

2nd update the count

```
update ip_data_yearly y 
set count= count + 
  (select count(j.ip_adress) from jan_table where j.ip_adress=y.ip_adress);
```

..

3rd do this for all months

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
I Assume Unique index on IP_Address .. then

```
INSERT INTO  ip_data_yearly (ip_adress) 
SELECT IP_Address FROM IP_Data_January
UNION ALL SELECT IP_Address FROM IP_Data_February 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
```